# Jquery dialog, use custom html element as the title

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an HTML form that I want to use several times in my site, so it's packed in a view and everytime I want to use it I load the same view. Sometimes I am using it in a [jquery dialog widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) that is working as a modal.

As I already have a title defined in my form, I would like to use that as the dialog titlebar, replacing the one by default. However I would like to keep the default functionalities: the close button and the fact that is draggable.

The original HTML

```html
<div id="form-info">
    <p class="title">The title</p>
    <form>
        <!--the form-->
    </form>
</div>
```

The html after jQuery `dialog()` runs

```html
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    <span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span>
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button>
</div>
<div id="form-info" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <p class="title">The title</p>
    <form>
         <!--the form-->
    </form> 
</div>
```

What I would like to achive:

```html
<div id="form-info" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <p class="title ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        The title
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close"></button>
    </p>
    <form>
         <!--the form-->
    </form> 
</div>
```

`span` tags inside the `ui-dialog-titlebar` are optional, I don't need them but I don't care if jQuery puts them there.

I've found many Q&A about hiding the title, customizing it with CSS, hiding the close button... but nothing quite like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont need the paragraph in other places you could just change your markup to

```
<div id="form-info" title="The title">
<form>
    <!--the form-->
</form>
</div>
```

or if you need it you could move the title during the open-event of your dialog like this

```
$("div#form-info").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    open: function() {
             var $formTitle = $("p.title", this);
             $(this).prev().find(".ui-dialog-title").text($formTitle.text());
             $formTitle.remove();
    }
});
```

for a working example see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KP2PN/1/)

Comment: yes that's the whole point, that I need it in other places so the HTML should remain untouchable. Moving the title during the open event seems to work great, thanks!

Comment: I've also found out that I can use the 'title' option to pass the text, like that `title: $('#form-info').find('.title').text()`. Seems a little more clear.